# Retrieving unit duration data from csv file using DictReader

Tags: python, csv, data-science, data-analysis

I have a long list of tasks in a CSV file. Each row has a column name with duration in a format like 10 seconds, 1-2 hours, 1 hour.10 minutes, etc. I want to convert these times into seconds:

[image: see example here]

Please guide.

Comment: Can you add a few example rows of the CSV to your question? Please then show what your expected output would be

Answer (score 1):

You will need to parse each entry depending on the unit. A regular expression could be used to extract the digits. For example:

```
import csv
import re

with open('input.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.DictReader(f_input)
    
    for row in csv_input:
        duration = row['duration(hours/minutes)']
        last_digits = int(re.findall(r'\d+', duration)[-1])
        
        if 'second' in duration:
            seconds = last_digits
        elif 'minute' in duration:
            seconds = last_digits * 60
        elif 'hour' in duration:
            seconds = last_digits * 3600
        else:
            print(f"{duration} - not understood")
        
        print(f"{duration}, convert {last_digits} into {seconds} seconds")
```

This would display:

```
24 minutes, convert 24 into 1440 seconds
13 seconds, convert 13 into 13 seconds
1-2 hours, convert 2 into 7200 seconds
>3 hours, convert 3 into 10800 seconds
11 seconds, convert 11 into 11 seconds
2 minutes, convert 2 into 120 seconds
8-9 minutes, convert 9 into 540 seconds
```